# Change Alpine Linux default shell

Tags: bash, shell, alpine

Alpine defaults to ash as the login shell, I want to change it to bash.

What I did so far:

- installed bash  by `sudo apk add bash`
- installed shadow by `sudo apk add shadow`
- I changed my user's login shell to `/bin/bash` with `chsh`
- checked that `/etc/passwd` contains `/bin/bash` as default login shell for my user

but that seems to be ignored. When I login (on console or ssh) I always end up in the ash shell.

Comment: See https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Change_default_shell

Answer (score 0):

How do you login? I just had a similar problem which appeared to have a different origin, but checked by docker exec with root user and then doing `su myuser` and the shell is bash:

```
8a0deef473ac:/var/www$ echo $0
bash
```

Answer (score -1):

As with "regular" Linux, you must use `chsh` to change your shell. Install it with:

```
apk add shadow
```

I like to use `bash`. To install it:

```
apk add bash
```

Then you can change your shell (or someone else's) with:

```
chsh $USER --shell /bin/bash
```

Logoff and log back in to enjoy your new shell.